# attribute [Route] is not working without [RoutePrefix] in ASP.NET WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Refer to the official [ASP.NET attribute routing documentation](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2), it seems that `Route` attribute can be used without `RoutePrefix`.

But, in my webapi controller, below cases are happened.

**1. Not working.** (error: No matched http route found)

```
public class GroupController : ApiController
{
    [Route("api/group/{id}/register")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(int id, InputModel model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

**2. Working good.**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/group")]
public class GroupController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id}/register")]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(int id, InputModel model)
    {
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Is it right that `Route` attribute should be used with `RoutePrefix`, or what am I missing?

In addition, below code is my WebApi route config in WebApiConfig.Register class.

```
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{subId}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, subId = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: I tried and its working for me both the way. Try spell checking the routes or something else might be ...

Comment: It is working for me as well... just wanted to ensure the address you are calling is correct client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49406/");  
await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/group/2/register", model);

Comment: Are you maybe not referencing the correct `RouteAttribute`? The one you want is in the `Http` namespace, not the `Mvc` namespace